# How can I have my own Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support

Is it possible for me to make a Q&A site like Stack Overflow for a different topic? How much money will it cost?

I have my own VPS; can I host the site there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of 2018, Stack Overflow has launched [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), which effectively give you a way of using Stack Overflow for your team without a private on-premise installation of the 'enterprise' version (and much cheaper, it'd seem to me).

Original answer:

[Stack Overflow Enterprise is available](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal use, but it is really meant for larger organizations only.

If you'd like to make your own Q&A platform, you can try one of the [open-source alternatives  to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones), or you can go through the [Area51 proposal process](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and see if your idea has a community around it.

Comment: do you have any example website run with Teams or is that not possible? (like is teams a thing that won't run with a web interface to it?)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). It is a staging zone for new sites.

Comment: This is true, but not what the OP was looking for. The answer to the OP's question, as George said, is "no."

Comment: @Popular, the OP wanted a SE site but on a different topic.  Although the OP is willing to pay and host, it did not seem like a requirement.  So, if they are just looking for a different SE site or have a new idea then area51 is the place to go.  The OP has no related accounts and might not be aware that other sites exist.

Comment: Hm, I read it as "I specifically want to buy a private SE site but my English is no good." But your way makes sense too. (More interesting is the fact that there are no related accounts; I didn't think that was even possible. Perhaps he had one but broke the association?)

Comment: We have a Facebook group for a certain chronic medical condition.  I would love to start a q&a site stackoverflow.com style because the questions are often repeated and information in Facebook groups is very hard to search .