# Can we have security stack overflow?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have my own Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82159/how-can-i-have-my-own-stack-exchange-site)

Hello,
Same as other stacks can you add security related stacks? it will be helpful from novice to advanced users.

Comment: For others who may come along later, the general answer to this class of questions is ["Go to area51"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 12):

Already [got one](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6):

In the case of a Stack Exchange for security, we do [already have one](http://security.stackexchange.com) as [Shadow Wizard mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91604/can-we-have-security-stack-overflow/91605#91605).

For general/future reference, please make sure that you check the following links:

- [A list of all existing Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)
- [A list of all Area 51 proposals for new sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com)